# Map Vim shortcut for Diffget

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I'm mapping shortcuts for :diffget //2 and :diffget //3 and :Gwrite! to make merging easier. So far, on the Mac, I have:

```
map <D-2> :diffget //2<CR>
map <D-3> :diffget //3<CR>
map <D-0> :Gwrite!<CR>
```

But unfortunately, they don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me on MacVim. are you using MacVim or terminal Vim?

Comment: The command key works only in MacVim. See `:help mapleader` for a cross-platform and far better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping definitions look fine. (You should prefer `:noremap`, though, as usually, remapping of the right-hand side isn't necessary, and may cause problems.) Especially in console Vim, not all key combinations can be used.

Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Sorry, I don't know much about the Mac.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination.